# Проблема с react после установки на сервре nginx

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, веб-сервер

Я установил сайт на react на nginx сервер(по идее все должно быть ок,тк я следовал инструкиям)
Но при перехрле по ip сервреа у меня появились такие ошибки =>

https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/static/css/main.6094b2de.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/static/js/main.524d9c99.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
итд..

я предполагаю, что проблема в том, что запрос отправляется на https, потому что, если перейти по этой ссылке в браузере < https://xx.xxx.xx.xxx/static/css/main.6094b2de.css > и изменить https на http Я получить некоторые данные

```
  server {
  listen 80;


  location / {
        root /var/www/myWebsite/client/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

   location /api {
        proxy_pass http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:8800;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }

}
```

Comment: У вас сервер на каком порту запускается? Судя по тому, что вы указали, порт 80, а это http порт. Запустите сервер на 443 порту(для https), а так же потребуется серверный сертификат

Comment: @SwaD поменять в натсройках nginx?

Comment: В вашем хттп сервере, который обеспечивает логику бэкэнда. У вас в метках указан nodejs, подумал что сервер это приложение на nodejs. и еще, вот такие файлы у вас на сервер есть main.6094b2de.css?

Comment: @SwaD Бэкенд открыт на порту 8080 и вроде как работает без проблем,а проблема именно с фронтом,который написан на реакте
index.html открывается,но к css и js получить доступ не может(

файлы main.6094b2de.css есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема скрылась в файле index.html,а конкретно в этой строчке

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Comment: Детализируйте, что именно в этой строчке было не так, на что влияло, на что поменяли и почему это заработало!

Comment: @SwaD так не разобрался в чем именно была проблема, но методом "тыка" получилось все запустить удалив эту строчку из html файла ¯\_(ツ)_/¯